# Next.js compiles but nothing loads

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I am running the newest version of everything...

Here is what is in my package.json:

[image]

Here is the chrome page it keeps loading... its been 2 hours:

[image]
Here is what the terminal shows:

[image]

Comment: Did you check console for errors. Also can you paste your base (Minimum version) code?

Comment: I did go over the console errors, this error started yesterday randomly, before that everything was working fine. All my projects are now acting up..

Comment: If you think your system is at fault, you can create a Next.js project on Codesandbox and try it out there. It would be helpful if you could share the link to your Codesandbox as well.